# MySQL- Selecting data from two tables and ordering by max values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with different num rows and I have volumns vote_up this value is different for every row in 2 tables. I need to union 2 tables and order by max vote_up value.
Here is my try, but get just 1 result:

```
SELECT name, vote_up 
FROM ( 
   SELECT name, vote_up 
   FROM comments 

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT name, vote_up 
   FROM replays ) T 
ORDER BY MAX(vote_up) DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to `order` the result in `Vote_up DESC` order and you don't want to filter any rows so remove `Max` from `order by`

```
SELECT name, vote_up 
FROM 
( 
SELECT name, vote_up 
FROM comments 
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, vote_up 
FROM replays
) T 
ORDER BY vote_up DESC
```